# mouseover jquery on sibling elements flick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        $(this).siblings('span').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {

        $(this).siblings('span').show().hide();
    }
}, "div");
```

I place my html like this

```
<div></div>
<span>x</span>
```

It flicks when I hover over the span, how to solve that without moving the span as child into the box in DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That  is because you have not attached the event correctly:

```
$('body div').hover(function(){//mouseover event
  $(this).next().show();
},function(){//mouseleave event
  $(this).next().hide();
});
```

You can also narrow down the code to use `.toggle()` on hover:

```
$('body').on('hover','div',function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: can't it be mouseenter and mouseleave event??

Comment: the two argument function in hover represents mouseover and mouseleave events respectively.

Comment: will this work for future element? I have to use on()

Answer (score 0):

As you want to bind event to span:

```
$('body').on("hover", "span", function(){
  $(this).show();
},function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

You can even use mouseenter and mouseleave as well:

```
 $('body').on("mouseenter","span", function(){
      $(this).show();
    }).on("mouseleave", "span",function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
```